# Soma de valores com javascript, apresenta erro?

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma solução que faz a soma de valores com relação ao value de um `input check` somente se este estiver selecionado, mas se selecionar os itens do primeiro ao ultimo a soma é feita normalmente mas se seleciona apenas os ultimos `input` da tabela o valor fica zerado, segue amostra do código.

```js
function selecionaDactes() {
  var ids = document.getElementsByClassName('editar');
  gravaArray(ids);
}

function gravaArray(dados) {
  var array_dados = dados;
  var teste = Array();
  var valor = Array();
  for (var x = 0; x <= array_dados.length; x++) {
    if (typeof array_dados[x] == 'object') {
      if (array_dados[x].checked) {
        teste[x] = array_dados[x].id;
        valor[x] = parseFloat(array_dados[x].value);
      }
    }
  }
  teste = teste.filter(Boolean);
  document.getElementById('docs').value = teste;
  valorTotal(valor);
}

function valorTotal(valor) {
  var array_valores = valor;
  var total = 0;
  for (var a = 0; a <= Object.keys(array_valores).length; a++) {
    if (array_valores[a] != '' && array_valores[a] != undefined && array_valores[a] != NaN) {
      total = parseFloat(total + array_valores[a]);
    }
  }
  total = total.toLocaleString('pt-br', {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    currency: 'BRL'
  });
  document.getElementById('valor').value = total;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form name="teste" method="#" action="">
  <label>Documents:
  <input type="text" name="docs" id="docs"/></label>
  <br>
  <label>Values:
  <input type="text" name="valor" id="valor"/></label>
  <br>
</form>
<table id="tbl_dactes" border="0" class="table table-condensed table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th align="center">#</th>
      <th>Transportador</th>
      <th>Conhecimento</th>
      <th>R$ Frete</th>
      <th>Data Emissão</th>
      <th>Fornecedor</th>
      <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="438283" value="65.58"> </td>
      <td>Dll logistica</td>
      <td>438283</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 65,58</span></td>
      <td>03/05/2017</td>
      <td>Aliexpress</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="3171" value="73.62"> </td>
      <td>Inter Modal</td>
      <td>3171</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 73,62</span></td>
      <td>05/05/2017</td>
      <td>Ebay</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="191513" value="65"> </td>
      <td>Italian Group Global</td>
      <td>191513</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 65,00</span></td>
      <td>09/05/2017</td>
      <td>FastBay</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="18977" value="157.74"> </td>
      <td>All In Global</td>
      <td>18977</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 157,74</span></td>
      <td>08/05/2017</td>
      <td>Tesla</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="18969" value="181.32"> </td>
      <td>Inter Modal</td>
      <td>18969</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 181,32</span></td>
      <td>08/05/2017</td>
      <td>Adidas</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="190999" value="65"> </td>
      <td>Global Latin</td>
      <td>190999</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 65,00</span></td>
      <td>04/05/2017</td>
      <td>Footage</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="1296" value="253.34"> </td>
      <td>E-Log Transportes Rodoviarios LTDA</td>
      <td>1296</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 253,34</span></td>
      <td>09/05/2017</td>
      <td>Nike</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="431587" value="191.25"> </td>
      <td>Vast</td>
      <td>431587</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 191,25</span></td>
      <td>30/03/2017</td>
      <td>Etti</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="5161" value="400.92"> </td>
      <td>Tico Tico</td>
      <td>5161</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 400,92</span></td>
      <td>29/04/2017</td>
      <td>LaCoste</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="18216" value="148.8"> </td>
      <td>Italian Log</td>
      <td>18216</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 148,80</span></td>
      <td>21/04/2017</td>
      <td>Vine</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="435335" value="377.15"> </td>
      <td>Porto Ferreira Portugal xpress</td>
      <td>435335</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 377,15</span></td>
      <td>18/04/2017</td>
      <td>Sardinha</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

se eu selecionar apenas os 2 ultimos registros o valor fica 0,00, não estou encontrando o erro, creio que o erro esteja ao gerar o array com os valores.

Comment: Explica melhor a relação entre checkbox e o `+` no final de cada linha. Deve ir somando? ou somar todos de uma vez carregando em qualquer `+`?

Comment: O mais no final é um botão que chama a função que faz a soma dos inputs selecionados. e apresenta esta soma em outro input com o total, apenas o selecionados devem ser somados.

Comment: Ok, para ficar bem claro para mim: mais no final  de cada linha faz a soma de todos os que estão selecionados e não só da linha clicada, é isso?

Comment: Exatamente, ela é genérica eu deveria colocar apenas um botão no inicio da tabela mas como minha tabela é muito grande coloquei em todas as linhas. vou arrumar isto depois.

Comment: Coloquei uma resposta com código mais simples. Podias fazer esses calculos com o evento `change` do checkbox e usar um icon de `edit` como o nome da coluna sugere (deixando de lado o `+`). Ou então usar o `+` para quantidades.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se entendi bem o problema, acontece que quando tu preenche o `array` valor, tu usa

`valor[x] = parseFloat(array_dados[x].value);`

nota que isso pode acarretar em preencher sem uma ordem, pois ele só vai adicionar no `array` quando a condição  `if(array_dados[x].checked)` for satisfeita.

Simplesmente adicionei um contador auxiliar `contAux` para definir o índice no `array` e o algoritmo funcionou como esperado.

```js
function selecionaDactes() {
  var ids = document.getElementsByClassName('editar');

  gravaArray(ids);
}

function gravaArray(dados) {
  var array_dados = dados;
  var contAux = 0;
  var teste = Array();
  var valor = Array();

  for (var x = 0; x <= array_dados.length; x++) {
    if (typeof array_dados[x] == 'object') {
      if (array_dados[x].checked) {
        teste[x] = array_dados[x].id;
        //valor[x] = parseFloat(array_dados[x].value);
        valor[contAux] = parseFloat(array_dados[x].value);
        contAux++;
      }
    }
  }
  teste = teste.filter(Boolean);
  document.getElementById('docs').value = teste;
  valorTotal(valor);
}

function valorTotal(valor) {
  var array_valores = valor;
  var total = 0;

  for (var a = 0; a <= Object.keys(array_valores).length; a++) {
    if (array_valores[a] != '' && array_valores[a] != undefined && array_valores[a] != NaN) {

      total = parseFloat(total + array_valores[a]);
    }
  }

  total = total.toLocaleString('pt-br', {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    currency: 'BRL'
  });
  //alert(total);

  document.getElementById('valor').value = total;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form name="teste" method="#" action="">
  <label>Documents:
  <input type="text" name="docs" id="docs"/></label>
  <br>
  <label>Values:
  <input type="text" name="valor" id="valor"/></label>
  <br>
</form>
<table id="tbl_dactes" border="0" class="table table-condensed table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th align="center">#</th>
      <th>Transportador</th>
      <th>Conhecimento</th>
      <th>R$ Frete</th>
      <th>Data Emissão</th>
      <th>Fornecedor</th>
      <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="438283" value="65.58"> </td>
      <td>Dll logistica</td>
      <td>438283</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 65,58</span></td>
      <td>03/05/2017</td>
      <td>Aliexpress</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="3171" value="73.62"> </td>
      <td>Inter Modal</td>
      <td>3171</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 73,62</span></td>
      <td>05/05/2017</td>
      <td>Ebay</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="191513" value="65"> </td>
      <td>Italian Group Global</td>
      <td>191513</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 65,00</span></td>
      <td>09/05/2017</td>
      <td>FastBay</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="18977" value="157.74"> </td>
      <td>All In Global</td>
      <td>18977</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 157,74</span></td>
      <td>08/05/2017</td>
      <td>Tesla</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="18969" value="181.32"> </td>
      <td>Inter Modal</td>
      <td>18969</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 181,32</span></td>
      <td>08/05/2017</td>
      <td>Adidas</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="190999" value="65"> </td>
      <td>Global Latin</td>
      <td>190999</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 65,00</span></td>
      <td>04/05/2017</td>
      <td>Footage</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="1296" value="253.34"> </td>
      <td>E-Log Transportes Rodoviarios LTDA</td>
      <td>1296</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 253,34</span></td>
      <td>09/05/2017</td>
      <td>Nike</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="431587" value="191.25"> </td>
      <td>Vast</td>
      <td>431587</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 191,25</span></td>
      <td>30/03/2017</td>
      <td>Etti</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="5161" value="400.92"> </td>
      <td>Tico Tico</td>
      <td>5161</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 400,92</span></td>
      <td>29/04/2017</td>
      <td>LaCoste</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="18216" value="148.8"> </td>
      <td>Italian Log</td>
      <td>18216</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 148,80</span></td>
      <td>21/04/2017</td>
      <td>Vine</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="435335" value="377.15"> </td>
      <td>Porto Ferreira Portugal xpress</td>
      <td>435335</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 377,15</span></td>
      <td>18/04/2017</td>
      <td>Sardinha</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Nesse outro snippet, deixei indicado no console o **erro** que estava acontecendo com o teu código, basta por exemplo, marcar o último `checkbox` e clicar para fazer o cálculo

```js
function selecionaDactes() {
  var ids = document.getElementsByClassName('editar');

  gravaArray(ids);
}

function gravaArray(dados) {
  var array_dados = dados;
  var contAux = 0;
  var teste = Array();
  var valor = Array();

  for (var x = 0; x <= array_dados.length; x++) {
    if (typeof array_dados[x] == 'object') {
      if (array_dados[x].checked) {
        teste[x] = array_dados[x].id;
        valor[x] = parseFloat(array_dados[x].value);
        //valor[contAux] = parseFloat(array_dados[x].value);
        contAux++;
      }
    }
  }
  teste = teste.filter(Boolean);
  document.getElementById('docs').value = teste;
  valorTotal(valor);
}

function valorTotal(valor) {
  var array_valores = valor;
  var total = 0;
  console.log(valor);
  for (var a = 0; a <= Object.keys(array_valores).length; a++) {
    if (array_valores[a] != '' && array_valores[a] != undefined && array_valores[a] != NaN) {

      total = parseFloat(total + array_valores[a]);
    }
  }

  total = total.toLocaleString('pt-br', {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    currency: 'BRL'
  });
  //alert(total);

  document.getElementById('valor').value = total;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form name="teste" method="#" action="">
  <label>Documents:
  <input type="text" name="docs" id="docs"/></label>
  <br>
  <label>Values:
  <input type="text" name="valor" id="valor"/></label>
  <br>
</form>
<table id="tbl_dactes" border="0" class="table table-condensed table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th align="center">#</th>
      <th>Transportador</th>
      <th>Conhecimento</th>
      <th>R$ Frete</th>
      <th>Data Emissão</th>
      <th>Fornecedor</th>
      <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="438283" value="65.58"> </td>
      <td>Dll logistica</td>
      <td>438283</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 65,58</span></td>
      <td>03/05/2017</td>
      <td>Aliexpress</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="3171" value="73.62"> </td>
      <td>Inter Modal</td>
      <td>3171</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 73,62</span></td>
      <td>05/05/2017</td>
      <td>Ebay</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="191513" value="65"> </td>
      <td>Italian Group Global</td>
      <td>191513</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 65,00</span></td>
      <td>09/05/2017</td>
      <td>FastBay</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="18977" value="157.74"> </td>
      <td>All In Global</td>
      <td>18977</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 157,74</span></td>
      <td>08/05/2017</td>
      <td>Tesla</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="18969" value="181.32"> </td>
      <td>Inter Modal</td>
      <td>18969</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 181,32</span></td>
      <td>08/05/2017</td>
      <td>Adidas</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="190999" value="65"> </td>
      <td>Global Latin</td>
      <td>190999</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 65,00</span></td>
      <td>04/05/2017</td>
      <td>Footage</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="1296" value="253.34"> </td>
      <td>E-Log Transportes Rodoviarios LTDA</td>
      <td>1296</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 253,34</span></td>
      <td>09/05/2017</td>
      <td>Nike</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="431587" value="191.25"> </td>
      <td>Vast</td>
      <td>431587</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 191,25</span></td>
      <td>30/03/2017</td>
      <td>Etti</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="5161" value="400.92"> </td>
      <td>Tico Tico</td>
      <td>5161</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 400,92</span></td>
      <td>29/04/2017</td>
      <td>LaCoste</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="18216" value="148.8"> </td>
      <td>Italian Log</td>
      <td>18216</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 148,80</span></td>
      <td>21/04/2017</td>
      <td>Vine</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="435335" value="377.15"> </td>
      <td>Porto Ferreira Portugal xpress</td>
      <td>435335</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 377,15</span></td>
      <td>18/04/2017</td>
      <td>Sardinha</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Então eu não poderia usar o próprio contador do "for()"?, ou o erro é porque não iniciei a chave do array em 0?

Comment: @WagnerFernandoMomesso Poder tu pode, mas ai o problema vai ser na função `valorTotal()`, pois nela o `for` vai até `Object.keys(array_valores).length` e se você marcar por exemplo, somente o último check box, o `Object.keys(array_valores).length` vai ser 1, e o array valor vai possuir 11 keys, sendo elas 10 undefined e a última com o valor correto.

Comment: @WagnerFernandoMomesso Talvez minha explicação tenha ficado meia confusa, editei a resposta adicionando ao final dela um outro snippet mostrando o que estava acontecendo com o teu código.

Comment: muito obrigado, agora entendi o erro, preciso aprender a fazer debug de javascript, ainda não sei usar debug, apenas em php, pergunta minha lógica de reciocinio estava certa?

Comment: Acredito que estava sim, foi um erro bem básico, mas considere a resposta do @Sergio, está bem clara e objetiva, utiliza funções específicas, evitando o uso de tantos loop's, assim fica mais fácil até de encontrar um possível erro :D

Answer (score 2):

Mudei o teu código para ficar mais simples, principalmente porque podes fazer um seletor com `:checked` e assim não precisares dos loops.

```js
function selecionaDactes() {
  var selecionados = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#tbl_dactes :checked'));

  var ids = selecionados.map(function(el) {
    return el.id;
  }).join(', ');
  document.getElementById('docs').value = ids;


  var total = selecionados.reduce(function(soma, el) {
    return soma + Number(el.value);
  }, 0);
  document.getElementById('valor').value = total.toLocaleString('pt-br', {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    currency: 'BRL'
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form name="teste" method="#" action="">
  <label>Documents:
  <input type="text" name="docs" id="docs"/></label>
  <br>
  <label>Values:
  <input type="text" name="valor" id="valor"/></label>
  <br>
</form>
<table id="tbl_dactes" border="0" class="table table-condensed table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th align="center">#</th>
      <th>Transportador</th>
      <th>Conhecimento</th>
      <th>R$ Frete</th>
      <th>Data Emissão</th>
      <th>Fornecedor</th>
      <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="438283" value="65.58"> </td>
      <td>Dll logistica</td>
      <td>438283</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 65,58</span></td>
      <td>03/05/2017</td>
      <td>Aliexpress</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="3171" value="73.62"> </td>
      <td>Inter Modal</td>
      <td>3171</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 73,62</span></td>
      <td>05/05/2017</td>
      <td>Ebay</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="191513" value="65"> </td>
      <td>Italian Group Global</td>
      <td>191513</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 65,00</span></td>
      <td>09/05/2017</td>
      <td>FastBay</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="18977" value="157.74"> </td>
      <td>All In Global</td>
      <td>18977</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 157,74</span></td>
      <td>08/05/2017</td>
      <td>Tesla</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="18969" value="181.32"> </td>
      <td>Inter Modal</td>
      <td>18969</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 181,32</span></td>
      <td>08/05/2017</td>
      <td>Adidas</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="190999" value="65"> </td>
      <td>Global Latin</td>
      <td>190999</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 65,00</span></td>
      <td>04/05/2017</td>
      <td>Footage</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="1296" value="253.34"> </td>
      <td>E-Log Transportes Rodoviarios LTDA</td>
      <td>1296</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 253,34</span></td>
      <td>09/05/2017</td>
      <td>Nike</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="431587" value="191.25"> </td>
      <td>Vast</td>
      <td>431587</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 191,25</span></td>
      <td>30/03/2017</td>
      <td>Etti</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="5161" value="400.92"> </td>
      <td>Tico Tico</td>
      <td>5161</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 400,92</span></td>
      <td>29/04/2017</td>
      <td>LaCoste</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="18216" value="148.8"> </td>
      <td>Italian Log</td>
      <td>18216</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 148,80</span></td>
      <td>21/04/2017</td>
      <td>Vine</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="435335" value="377.15"> </td>
      <td>Porto Ferreira Portugal xpress</td>
      <td>435335</td>
      <td><span class="valor_dacte">R$ 377,15</span></td>
      <td>18/04/2017</td>
      <td>Sardinha</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dan" onclick="selecionaDactes()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></td>
      <!-- inicio modal -->

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: seu código é muito limpo, não imaginei que poderia usar assim também, queria marcar as duas respostas como resolvida mas não posso, a solução anterior resolveu meu problema de imediato, o seu também mas antes de marca-la como resolvida preciso fazer alguns códigos parecidos com este para minimizar o meu e ir entendendo. um caso novo foi o "join" eu ainda não fiz nada com ele, estou acostumado trabalhar direto com os inputs, mas vi que posso trabalhar diretamente na tabela, isso é novidade pra mim. obrigado.